# How can I tune material values with the slider in the Unity inspector more finely?

Tags: unity

I'm adjusting a material's texture tiling and offset values in the editor but its increments are too large and it's jumping over the value I need. Is there a way to slow it down or adjust the amount it increments by (without using a custom script)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the slider is skipping over the value you need, why can't you just enter it in the value box?? It looks like you can also hold ALT down, which will give you some more granularity when using the slider